# Write a program that finds a phrase and print out

Tags: shell, grep

I need to write a shell script that finds the phrase "Candy Land" and prints out the 10 lines surrounding the line where that word is found. Assume it is only found once.

I don't know what it means by shell program and by printing the 10 lines surrounding that word. Maybe using head/tail.

I know using grep you can find the phrase by doing this:

```
grep 'Candy Land' file
```

But I don't think this is what I'm suppose to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep has couple of flags such as `-A` for displaying the number line after the match and `-B` for displaying the number lines before the match both expects a number followed by the flag.

And the flag `-C` can also be used which combines both to give you one line both before and after.

For example,

```
grep -A 1 -B 1 'Candy Land' file
```

or

```
grep -C 1 'Candy Land' file
```

Comment: If I change the 1 to a 10 it will show 10 lines?

Comment: Yup...  Any number you give it displays that many number of lines.